# How do I make the form options to pop on the left side of the label of a radio button

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, frontend

I have written the following:

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~.reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  /* little bit of a magic number :( */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs">
  <label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label>
  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <input type="text" name="dog" placeholder="why?">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-cats">
  <label for="choice-animals-cats">I like cats more</label>
  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <input type="text" name="cat" placeholder="why?">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the output of this code is:

[image]

So, how do I go about creating a code by which I can make the text boxes that are being revealed by clicking on the radio buttons on the left side of the labels of those radio buttons?

I have tried using tables to actually arrange the radio buttons and then try and display the hidden text boxes on the next cell beside the label, but it hasn't helped, as using a table somehow disables the popups.

Any help on the matter would be really appreciated!

Comment: if you add display: inline-block to .reveal-if-active you have the desired effect?

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about! Thanks @FabrizioCalderan! It totally helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @FabioCalderan's comment and thanks to him, we can simply add **display:inline-block** to the class **.reveal-if-active** to pop the options on the same line as the radio button and the label.

```css
.reveal-if-active {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~.reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.reveal-if-active {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 100px;
  /* little bit of a magic number :( */
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs">
  <label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label>
  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <input type="text" name="dog" placeholder="why?">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-cats">
  <label for="choice-animals-cats">I like cats more</label>
  <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <input type="text" name="cat" placeholder="why?">
  </div>
</div>
```